# How do I add a quit button to this program? How about "clear"?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, layout-manager

I need to add a button that "clears the calculator" and also one that quits the program on the butPanel. It also needs to be very basic Java code because I am a beginner and have an awful comp.sci. teacher. I have a sample of code that has the quit button, but I am unsure of how to put it into MY program. I've tried so much. 
Also if there is a better way to "error-check" that would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel heading = new JLabel ("2. Calculator");
    JLabel intro1 = new JLabel ("This program stimulates a four-function calculator.");
    JLabel intro2 = new JLabel ("It takes an operator and a number. It can add, subtract,");
    JLabel intro3 = new JLabel (" multiply and divide. Enter in the format eg. '+35'. ");
    JLabel inLabel = new JLabel ("        Operation: ");
    JLabel outLabel = new JLabel ("       Total:           ");
    JTextField inOper = new JTextField (7);
    JTextField outTota = new JTextField (7); // intro

//panels
JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel ();
JPanel intro1Panel = new JPanel ();
JPanel intro2Panel = new JPanel ();
JPanel intro3Panel = new JPanel ();
JPanel operPanel = new JPanel ();
JPanel totaPanel = new JPanel ();
JPanel butPanel = new JPanel ();

String operTemp;
String totaTemp;

public Calculator2 ()
{
    setTitle ("C - 2.");
    inOper.addActionListener (this);
    outTota.setEditable (false);
    getContentPane ().setLayout (new FlowLayout ());

    titlePanel.add (heading);
    intro1Panel.add (intro1);
    intro2Panel.add (intro2);
    intro3Panel.add (intro3);
    operPanel.add (inLabel);
    operPanel.add (inOper);
    totaPanel.add (outLabel);
    totaPanel.add (outTota); //adds components to panels

    getContentPane ().add (titlePanel);
    getContentPane ().add (intro1Panel);
    getContentPane ().add (intro2Panel);
    getContentPane ().add (intro3Panel);
    getContentPane ().add (operPanel);
    getContentPane ().add (totaPanel); //Adds panels to Frame

    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


public static int isInteger (String input)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt (input);
        return Integer.parseInt (input);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        return 0;
    }
} //isInteger method


// The application
public String calculate (String operation, String newtotal)
{
    int total = isInteger (newtotal);
    String totalS;
    char operator;
    int number = 0;
    operator = operation.charAt (0);

    if (operator == '+')
    {
        number = isInteger (operation.substring (1));
        total = total + number;
        totalS = Integer.toString (total);
    }


    else if (operator == '-')
    {
        number = isInteger (operation.substring (1));
        total = total - number;
        totalS = Integer.toString (total);
    }


    else if (operator == '*')
    {
        number = isInteger (operation.substring (1));
        total = total * number;
        totalS = Integer.toString (total);
    }


    else if (operator == '/')
    {
        number = isInteger (operation.substring (1));
        total = total / number;
        totalS = Integer.toString (total);
    }
    else
    {
        totalS = ("ERROR");
    }

    if (number == 0)
    {
        totalS = ("ERROR");
    }
    return totalS;
} // calculate method


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)
{
    String userIn = inOper.getText ();
    String totalIn = outTota.getText ();
    try
    {
        totaTemp = calculate (userIn, totalIn);
        outTota.setText (totaTemp + "");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outTota.setText ("ERROR");
    }
    repaint ();
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Calculator2 calc = new Calculator2 ();
    calc.setSize (350, 350);
    calc.setResizable (false);
    calc.setVisible (true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

First declare the buttons and initialize them:

```
JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
```

Then, make sure the butPanel has a layout and the panel is added to the content pane:

```
butPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
getContentPane().add(butPanel);
```

Then add the action listeners on the new buttons:

```
exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
});
clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO: clear the stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I ignored that :)

Comment: yes i have all that, but i don't know WHERE to put it in my code :$

Comment: The buttons instantiation next to the other JLabel and JPanel instantiations. The other code somewhere in the constructor, where you have built the other UI stuff. However, you should move that code out of the constructor at some point.

Comment: I honestly wish I knew what that meant

Comment: The first 2 lines in my answer go after your JPanel butPanel = new JPanel (); line.

Comment: The other lines go after getContentPane ().add (totaPanel);